# How to control the auto suggest text at the top of on screen keyboard for android EditText controls

Tags: android, autocomplete, keyboard, android-edittext, autosuggest

When typing in an EditText control - some autocomplete/autosuggest words are made available at the top of the control.

Like below:
[image]

I have a situation where the user should only be entering words from a pre-known set of existing words. As such it would improve the user experience to control the autosuggest list, and have only words from this list appear.

All my searches on this subject have turned up is suggestions to use AutoCompleteTextView for this purpose, however this is not 100% ideal - below is a screenshot of AutoCompleteTextView in action:
[image]

The suggestions show as a popup list, and the top of the on screen keyboard now has unnecessary blank spaces.
So while this sort of 'works' - it isn't a 100% ideal user experience, it will feel 'hacky' to the user, and not as native/seamlessly integrated with the android experience as it should be.

So my main question(s)
1) Is there a way to either have the AutoCompleteTextView show its suggestions at the top of the on screen keyboard? 
2) Or even better/alternatively, is there a way to hook into the autosuggest/spelling feature of the on screen keyboard for EditText itself instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  InputMethodManager.displayCompletions will give the keyboard a list of possible completions.  Depending on the keyboard, it *should* display those but it may ignore them.  That's how ACTV works behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the right direction, however upon further digging I see that AutoCompleteTextView actually does call InputMethodManager.displayCompletions - yet the IME is displaying blanks instead.. Not sure whats going on here.

Comment: Could be the keyboard is ignoring then

Comment: It seems strange that it ignores them, because it blanks out the spots where it would normally show the suggestions, if it were outright ignoring them it would show its own suggestions like it does in a normal EditText.


Anyway it is what it is I guess, if it can't be done in a sensible way I'll just have to live with it like this.